# AngularJS how to keep an internal state in directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to maintain an internal state object inside the directive, which I can pass to controller as an argument to a function.

So that directive template looks something like this:

```
<div>
     <form name="Test">
         <input name="Name">
     </form>
     <button ng-click="submit(formValues)">Submit</button>
</div>
```

I't doesn't have to be a form, as long as I can pass all the values back to controller
as an argument in function.

http://jsfiddle.net/gqrjc/

Is this possible with angularJS or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking, but are you saying you want the `input` value? Try binding `ng-model="myModel"` to your input. You don't need to pass this value in, it'll be available in the controller via `$scope.myModel` for you to access onsubmit. I'd also recommend using `<form ng-submit="mySubmitFunction()">` which does all the preventDefault actions for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what scope's properties are for. Try binding your inputs with scope's properties using ng-model:

```
<div id="holder">
     <input name="something" value="" ng-model="something" />
         <input name="somethingelse" value="" ng-model="somethingelse"/>
         <button ng-click="eventHandler({param:[something, somethingelse]})">
              Call own function
         </button>
</div>
```

Notice that in order to use `&` function binding, you have to do it like this in your directive html, notice the param parameter.

```
submitter="myFirstFunction(param)"
```

And call it in your directive's scope like this:

```
eventHandler({param:[something, somethingelse]})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A6T9C/)

Comment: My GOD! you are a life saver, I did not know that I could just introduce models. I did not understand scopes fully. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the directive's controller for that.
The controller get's instantiated for each element the directive is declared on.
Something like this :

```
.directive (function () {
    return {
        controller: function () {
            var a = 'something really private' + new Date().getTime();
            this.getA = function () {
               return a;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

You have access to the scope by injecting it in the controller or as the 4th argument in the directives's link function.